# Web scraping sites with same URL with R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap this [website](http://serviciostelematicos.minhap.gob.es/PubInvCCAA/secciones/frmSelComunidad.aspx) with R, which is basically a data base of companies in Spain. I'd like to access to each single company (final URL: http://serviciostelematicos.minhap.gob.es/PubInvCCAA/secciones/FrmDatosG.aspx) and scrape the information.

There is some information passed to the server because the same final URL shows different companies depending on where you are coming from but I am completely stuck on how this information is sent.

I've tried different web scraping R-packages but none of them worked. Is there a way to navigate from R so that the cookies are sent the same way as if you were navigating from the browser?

I have read many questions so far and none of them seems to match my situation.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something like `RSelenium`.

Comment: My company personal laptop does not let me use Selenium due to some firewall. Is there any alternative to this package?